# how to make floating widget which can move in full screen area

Tags: android

i am following this tutorial (https://www.android-examples.com/floating-widget/) to make floating widget but it can only move in the middle of screen. Seems like the floating layout has a top&bottom padding?

I tried to set activity as noTitleBar but still doesn't work...

[image: you can see this icon can only move in partial screen]

this is the layout code of floating widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainParentRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <!-- This layout is the Collapsed layout -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout_Collapsed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Logo_Icon"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/mobile_icon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Widget_Close_Icon"
                android:layout_width="23dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/close_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- This layout is expended layout-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout_Expended"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF3E0"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/WebsiteLogoIcon"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/mobile_icon"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Android-Examples"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="23dp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="www.android-examples.com"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Try this, may be it's work for you: [FloatingChatHeads](https://github.com/anupamchugh/FloatingChatHeads)

Comment: it's the same code and the bubble can't move to the app title area. basically I want bubble to be able to move in the whole screen...still thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

figure it out myself...just need layout.nolimit